# LOG.info does not have option to format string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using the following logging module in python2.7

```
import logging
LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

where I am able to do
`LOG.warn("Namespace {0} is not compliant.").format(namespace)`

but not
`LOG.info("Namespace {0} is not compliant.").format(namespace)`

However this works:
`LOG.info("Namespace %s is hipaa compliant.", namespace)`

I am wondering why only LOG.info doesn't work.

Comment: Your syntax makes no sense. You're calling `.format()` on the **return value** of `LOG.warn()` which will have no effect on the arguments sent to it.

Comment: what does LOG.warn return? not a string?

Comment: Yeah, you need to apply `format()` to the string you're passing to the function, e.g. `LOG.warn("Namespace {0} is not compliant.".format(namespace))`

Comment: Don't you mean `warning()`, not `warn()`? **Edit:** Turns out `warn` is an alias for `warning`.

Comment: The `warn` call is also wrong; if you think it worked, you didn't really run the code you think you did. Pay attention to parenthesis placement.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
LOG.warn("Namespace {0} is not compliant.").format(namespace)
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
x = LOG.warn("Namespace {0} is not compliant.")

x.format(namespace)           # Return value unused
```

In other words:

- You're passing an unformatted string to `warn`.
- You're then calling `.format()` on that return value.

  - The return value of `Logger.warning` is unspecified, but is apparently a string.
  - Strings are immutable in Python, so this has no effect (since you don't save the result).

---

Instead you need to do this:

```
LOG.warn( "Namespace {0} is not compliant.".format(namespace) )
```